# pass object primary key across templates django

Tags: python, django, primary-key

new to python/django. I am using class based views. I have objects named `Video` that I want to be able to create ratings for. I have a `DetailView` for the `Video`, and on that same page I have a link that brings you to another page to rate the `Video` that was on the `DetailView` (because I have not wanted to mess with Mixins yet to have it all on the same page).

How can I keep/get the reference to the `DetailView` `Video` object so when I submit the rating it knows that the rating is for `Video` object that was on the `DetailView`?

models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Community Video   ")

class Rating(models.Model):
    rate_choice = ((1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'), (4, '4'), (5, '5'))
    rate_value = models.IntegerField(default=5, choices=rate_choice)
    video = models.ForeignKey('Video', related_name='video', null=True, default=1)
```

views.py

```
class VideoView(DetailView):
    model = Video
    template_name = 'video_view.html'


class RatingView(CreateView):
    model = Rating
    template_name = 'rating_create.html'
    fields = ['rate_value', 'video']
```

Basically I want the primary key of the `Video` to go with me when I go from the `video_view` to `rating_create` template. I am thinking of just using function based views, class views are confusing me.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload', UploadVideo.as_view(), name='upload'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', VideoView.as_view(), name='videoview'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/ratings', RatingView.as_view(success_url='success_yea'), name='rating_view'),
    url(r'^success', upload, name='success_yea')
]
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using function based views if you find them easier to understand. Whether you choose function based views or class based views, the first thing to do is set up your urls. What do you have for that so far?

Comment: I added urls to my post. I tried a few different things with adding a primary key in the url name, what I have here is just one of my attemps

Answer (score 2):

You can pass this as a parameters on your urls.py, something like

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/ratings', RatingView.as_view(),
```

In the `video_view.html` template file reverse it with the current video id.

And then in your view:

```
class RatingView(CreateView):
    model = Rating
    template_name = 'rating_create.html'
    fields = ['rate_value']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success_yea')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.video = get_object_or_404(Video, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return super(RatingView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: so this is putting the primary key of the `Video` in the url and then using `kwargs` to find that primary key and return that object to the view? I then need to save the rating to the object that was defined in `get_init` with another method in the view right?

Comment: Yes that's basically the idea, you can also create a custom ModelForm and make video field a hidden input or override form_valid method and save the model yourself with the right video instead of passing initial

Answer (score 0):

Your url looks good, you already have the pk there.

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/ratings', RatingView.as_view(), name='rating_view'),
```

In your view, you should remove `video` from the list of fields because you don't want it to be editable.

You can then override `form_valid` and set `video` on the form's instance.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404    
from django.urls import reverse

class RatingView(CreateView):
    model = Rating
    template_name = 'rating_create.html'
    fields = ['rate_value']
    # I recommend moving this here, to avoid splitting config between the view and the urls.
    # You need reverse_lazy to turn the pattern name into the url 
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success_yea')  

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Fetch video from the db to check it exists
        video = get_object_or_404(Video, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.video = video
        return super(RatingView, self).form_valid(form)
```

One disadvantage of the above code is that you only validate the pk in the url when the form is valid. If you would prefer to validate the primary key for all requests, you could move that code into the dispatch method.

```
class RatingView(CreateView):
    model = Rating
    template_name = 'rating_create.html'
    fields = ['rate_value']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success_yea')  

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Fetch video from the db to check it exists
        self.video = get_object_or_404(Video, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(RatingView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.video = self.video
        return super(RatingView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: ok i am a little confused on what you have here. What does `kwargs = super(RatingView, self).get_form_kwargs()` do? Is the only `kwarg` i need not `pk`? And do i need to initiate the instance somewhere, I dont really understand what that line is doing.

Comment: Note that this is one of the disadvantages of class based views - you can't look at the view and understand the flow without understanding what the methods like `form_valid` and `get_form_kwargs` do. I've changed the code to use `form_valid` instead because I think it's a bit cleaner. Calling `return super(RatingView, self).form_valid(form)` is calling the `CreateView`'s `form_valid` method so that we don't have to duplicate the code.